# perl: warning: Setting locale failed on macOS Sierra 10.12.4

Tags: perl, terminal, warnings, macos-sierra

Hey I got the above problem when I installed Hyper terminal and when i open the terminal I get this warning and I tried to set my .zshrc exports which
is well documented on google but it do not work.
So far I tried these exports:

```
export LC_ALL = (unset)
export LC_CTYPE = "da.UTF-8"
export LANG = "da.UTF-8"
```

edit 30 May 20:14
[see the warnings here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lam5Q.png)

Comment: Can see that I have inserted two comma and one dot by mistake but I had not done this in the .zshrc file

Comment: You can [edit] your question with the [edit] link below the tags.

Answer (score 1):

when I run `locale -a` it does show `da_DK.UTF-8` - using a locale that is actually installed on your system might help ?

running macOS Sierra Version 10.12.5

Comment: I have also da_DK.UTF-8 when I run locale -a, so a do not understand when yours work when mine do not.

Comment: did you actually try it with `da_DK.UTF-8` ... instead of the one in your question `da.UTF-8`

Comment: yeah I tried it and it still do not work. It's very weird :)